# client side datatable pagination

Tags: liferay-6, alloy-ui

Am using Alloy UI data table and i have client side pagination. Alloy ui data table has inbuilt pagination and am using it. is there any way to customize its style and things. for example, if we enable pagination, it will provide "page Sizes" and "first, previous, next, last" links and provision to go to pages  which i doesn't want.I have uploaded the default data table pagination image and the one i need . 
**Default**

[image]

**Needed**

[image]

How to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using Liferay 6.2, Liferay 6.1, or Liferay 6.0? Could you post a runnable or complete code example as well?

Comment: Am using Liferay 6.2. i have pasted the code below

Comment: var prodDataTable = new Y.DataTable({
           autoSync : true,
           columns : nestedCol,                                                
           data : [],                                                                                            
           width : "100%",
           rowsPerPage : 8,
           pageSizes : [ 10,20, { label: 'Show All'} ]
           paginatorLocation: ['footer']                                        
     }).render("#prodDataTableDiv");
    
    prodDataTable.set('data', JSON.parse(_value));

Answer (score 0):

ike you said, we had a similar requirement. Preferred using AUI DataTable along with Jquery pagination plugin.

Here I attached the [Link](http://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/) for JQuery opensource plugin for pagination. Its easy to use.